# Using Splice to delete desired elment onClick in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of Colours that after picking a colour i want to be able to delete any selected colour onClick. I cant seem to delete the one i want because i have set it like **splice(index, 1)**. any suggestions?

```
state = {
    colors: [],
    name: [],
    front: 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png',
    back: 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png'
  };

  deleteColor(color) {
    let colors = [...this.state.colors.slice()]
    const index = colors.findIndex(
      x => x.value === color.value
    )
    colors.splice(index, 1)
    this.setState({ colors: colors })
    console.log('Deleted')
  }
```

**Then in return**

```
<div
key={color.id}
 onClick={e => {
 e.stopPropagation()
 e.preventDefault()
 this.deleteColor(color)
}}
>
      //something
</div>
```

I would Want to delete any element onClick. thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to delete the array when you can reset it to empty?

Comment: @kushalvm that's not my problem. read again

Comment: colors.splice(index, color) - second argument is `color`. I think you want to make `colors.splice(index, 1)`

Comment: @AndriiGolubenko Yes, thanks but that always deletes the 2nd element of the array no matter which one i click

Answer (score 1):

You can make it all easier.

```
deleteColor = (color) => (e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  e.preventDefault()
  this.setState({ colors: this.state.colors.filter((el) => el.value !== color.value) })
}
```

```
<div
 key={color.id}
 onClick={this.deleteColor(color)}
>
      //something
</div>
```

Comment: so this is supposed to make me delete any item i want? Why dont you use splice?